# Converting sql query to EF query- nested query in from

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, entity-framework

Just wondering how the following sql query would look in linq for Entity Framework...

```
SELECT  KPI.*
FROM    KeyPerformanceIndicator KPI
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT  SPP.SportProgramPlanId
        FROM    SportProgramPlan PSPP
            INNER JOIN SportProgramPlan ASPP
                ON (PSPP.SportProgramPlanId = @SportProgramPlanId
                    AND PSPP.StartDate >= ASPP.StartDate
                    AND PSPP.EndDate <= ASPP.EndDate)
    ) AS SPP
        ON KPI.SportProgramPlanId = SPP.SportProgramPlanId
```

Cheers
Anthony

Comment: Some part of your query is missing -- there are two `(` and one `)`. Perhaps the start of the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Missing bracket fixed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say without seeing the associations in your model. Would there be a self-referential association on `SportProgramPlan`?

The SQL seems like an error to me as `PSPP` and `ASPP` could be the same record, and I'm not sure you want that? At any rate, it's trivial to exclude....

Here's a shot at it:

```
var q = from kpi in Context.KeyPerformanceIndicators
        where kpi.SportProgramPlan.Id = sportProgramPlanId 
            && Context.SportProgramPlans.Any(aspp => 
                                                 spp.StartDate >= aspp.StartDate
                                                 && spp.EndDate <= aspp.EndDate))
        select ...
```

Comment: I am trying to bring across the query you provided but the 'Any' method isn't a part of SportProgramPlans... any ideas?

Comment: KeyPerformanceIndicator has only 1 SportProgramPlan but 1 SportProgramPlan can have many KeyPerformanceIndicators...

Comment: OK; updated for that cardinality, but see the note; I'm not sure your original SQL is right.